# Equality of objects in Python

Tags: python, equality

I have a class `MyClass`, which contains two member variables `foo` and `bar`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
```

I have two instances of this class, each of which has identical values for `foo` and `bar`:

```
x = MyClass('foo', 'bar')
y = MyClass('foo', 'bar')
```

However, when I compare them for equality, Python returns `False`:

```
>>> x == y
False
```

How can I make python consider these two objects equal?

Comment: Override `__cmp__` method of the class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you have to tell python how exactly you want equality be defined.
do so by defining a special method `__eq__` like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.attrfoo == other.attrfoo # change that to your needs
```

the `__cmp__(self, other)` is the "old" style to compare instances of classes, and only used when there is no `rich comparison` special method found. read up on them here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames

Comment: If you define `__eq__`, remember to also define `__ne__` to prevent surprises.

Comment: Remember to define `__ne__` too: should be written explicitely in the answer. Forgetting it may be really tricky.

Answer (score 7):

The standard protocol is to define [`__cmp__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) or [`__eq__()` and `__ne__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

If you don't, Python uses object identity ("address") to compare objects.

Comment: do you mean python will check whether they are in the same memory?

Comment: That's an implementation detail, but for CPython it's like that.